# MQA.Nominatim: how do you pass various information to multiple MQA.Nominatim.constructPOI callbacks?

Tags: javascript, geocode, mapquest

I use the mapquest MQA.Nominatim module to geocode addresses inside my java script code. 
I would like to pass additional information to the callback function MQA.Nominatim.constructPOI.
This information should vary for each geolocation.
I use javascript closure to encapsulate the data in each callback function (this works as desired in the google geocoding api).
MQA.Nominatim always calls the last callback function being set. At a guess MQA.Nominatim.constructPOI is a some how global address pointer.
So I end up with all flags and additional information looking the same for all locations on the map.
Any ideas how to solve this ?

My code looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://open.mapquestapi.com/sdk/js/v7.0.s/mqa.toolkit.js?key=xxxxxxx"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var flags = ['icons/flag_green.png', 'icons/flag_red.png'];

        var addressArr = [
     [', 49084 Osnabrueck, Germany','R','/trac/start/ticket/6677','Repair #6677'],
     [', 39599 Uchtspringe, Germany','R','/trac/start/ticket/6670','Repair #6670'],
     [', 17491 Greifswald, Germany','I','/trac/start/ticket/6625','Install #6625'],
     [', 37269 Eschwege, Germany','R','/trac/start/ticket/6620','Repair #6620'],
     [', 57076 Siegen, Germany','R','/trac/start/ticket/6602','Repair #6602'],
     [', 3109 St Poelten, Germany','I','/trac/start/ticket/6598','Install #6598'],
     [', 45884 Gelsenkirchen, Austria','R','/trac/start/ticket/6594','Repair #6594'],
     [', 48653 Coesfeld, Germany','R','/trac/start/ticket/6588','Repair #6588']
        ];

     function locationsCallback (location, osmLocation) {
            var type = location[1];
            var url = location[2];
            var title = location[3];
            var image = flags[0];
            if ('R' == type)
                  image = flags[1];

            /*Override the custom POI generation*/
            var lat = osmLocation.lat;
            var lng = osmLocation.lon;
            var p = new MQA.Poi({
               lat : lat,
               lng : lng
            });
            var customIcon = new MQA.Icon(image, 20, 29);
            p.setIcon(customIcon);

            /*Override the custom text populating the InfoWindow content*/
            p.setRolloverContent('<div style="font-size:14px;">' + title + '</div>');
            p.setInfoContentHTML('<div style="font-size:14px; width:180px;">' + url + '</div>');
            return p;
        };

        // define a function wich does the actual work of the callback and a func
        function setMarker (location) {
            MQA.Nominatim.constructPOI = function (osmLocation) {
                var callbackLoc = location;
                return locationsCallback(callbackLoc, osmLocation);
            };

            /*Executes a Nominatim search and adds the result to the map*/
            map.nominatimSearchAndAddLocation(location[0], null);
        }

       function setMarkers () {
           for (var i = 0; i < addressArr.length; i++) {
                var thisLoc = addressArr[i];
                // alert("Iteration: " + i + "   Geocode: " + location);

                /*This uses the MQA.withModule support to download and initialize the Nominatim support module. The constructPOI
                method is called to override the default behavior of constructing a POI.*/
                setMarker(thisLoc);
            }

       }
        function initialize() {

            /*Create an object for options*/
            var options = {
               elt : document.getElementById('map'), /*ID of element on the page where you want the map added*/
               zoom : 11, /*initial zoom level of map*/
               latLng: { lat:50.202250, lng:10.079730 },    /*center of the map is Bad Kissingen*/
               mtype:'osm',                                 /*map type (osm)*/
               bestFitMargin: 0,                            /*margin offset from the map viewport when applying a bestfit on shapes*/
               zoomOnDoubleClick: true                      /*zoom in when double-clicking on map*/
            };

            /*Construct an instance of MQA.TileMap with the options object*/
            window.map = new MQA.TileMap(options);

            /*This uses the MQA.withModule support to download and initialize the Nominatim support module. The constructPOI
              method is called to override the default behavior of constructing a POI.*/
            MQA.withModule('nominatim', setMarkers);
        };

        MQA.EventUtil.observe(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='map' style='width:100%; height:750px;'></div>
</body>
```